# Changing JavaScript function definition gives Object doesn't support property or method on IE but works in chrome

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I initially had the following javascript function that is used in several of files (100+) literally on onclick of buttons.

```
function loadPage(CurrentPage, PageToMove) { 
//Something Here
}
```

Now I am changing this function to send one more default parameter like this

```
  function loadPage(CurrentPage, PageToMove, NewParam = false) { 
    //Something Here
   }
```

And this function is called by following

```
parent.frames[0].loadPage(20, 50);
```

While this works in chrome browser but not on recent version of IE.

It gives parent.frames[0] object doesn't support property or method error

If I inspect the methods on debugger after making changes to the function, i can't see the loadPage function is listed.

But before the change with just 2 parameters the method is available if I inspect in the debugger & it works as expected.

So how can I get this method support on IE with 3 parameters ?

Comment: Default parameters are part of ES6. In an ES5 environment, you can do `newParam = newParam || false`.

Comment: In JS you don't need to define the parameters in function declaration. You can as well do `function loadPage(CurrentPage, PageToMove) { NewParam = arguments[2]; if (NewParam == undefined) NewParam = false...`. You can read more about `arguments` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If removing the parameter fixes it then just do that.  You can do a check for a conditional 3rd parameter like this...

```
function loadPage(CurrentPage, PageToMove) { 
    //Something Here
    if (arguments.length > 2 && arguments[2] === true) {
        // 3rd parameter was passed and is == true so do what you need to do
    }
}
```

or alternatively, if you want the `NewParam` variable defined within the function...

```
function loadPage(CurrentPage, PageToMove) { 
    var NewParam = (arguments.length > 2 && arguments[2] === true);
    //Something Here
}
```

My preferred method, however, would be to remove the default value and just check the parameter inside the function...

```
function loadPage(CurrentPage, PageToMove, NewParam) { 
    if (typeof(NewParam) == "undefined") {
        NewParam = false;
    }
    //Something Here
}
```

Comment: This worked. 

However your preferred method didn't work as I am working on 10 year old code and IE7. It gives same error. 

First two solutions worked. Thanks :)

Comment: Ah okay.  That's a shame as I find that much cleaner and easier to read further down the line.  You said IE7 though, so I wish you luck :D  Glad I could help.